# gcloud startup script not running

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have the following python code:

```
def create_instance(compute_arg, project_arg, zone_arg, config="default", startup_script="", name="", instances=[],
                    strategy_args=[]):

    startup_script = """
    #! /bin/bash\n
    mkdir before_all;\n
    EOF
    """

    print name
    if config == "default":
        print 'config is default'
        config = {
            "name": name,
            "zone": "projects/my-project-12345/zones/us-east1-b",
            "machineType": "projects/my-project-12345/zones/us-east1-b/machineTypes/n1-standard-1",
            "metadata": {
                "items": [{'key': 'startup-script', 'value': startup_script}]
            },
            "tags": {
                "items": [
                    "http-server",
                    "https-server"
                ]
            },
            "disks": [
                {
                    "type": "PERSISTENT",
                    "boot": True,
                    "mode": "READ_WRITE",
                    "autoDelete": True,
                    "deviceName": "instance-6",
                    "initializeParams": {
                        "sourceImage": "projects/my-project-12345/global/images/image-root-git-algo",
                        "diskType": "projects/my-project-12345/zones/us-east1-b/diskTypes/pd-standard",
                        "diskSizeGb": "10"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "canIpForward": False,
            "networkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "network": "projects/my-project-12345/global/networks/default",
                    "subnetwork": "projects/my-project-12345/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/default",
                    "accessConfigs": [
                        {
                            "name": "External NAT",
                            "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "description": "",
            "labels": {},
            "scheduling": {
                "preemptible": False,
                "onHostMaintenance": "MIGRATE",
                "automaticRestart": True
            },
            "serviceAccounts": [
                {
                    "email": "123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
                    "scopes": [
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

    return compute_arg.instances().insert(
        project=project_arg,
        zone=zone_arg,
        body=config).execute()

compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute', 'v1') 
project = 'my-project-12345'
zone = 'us-east1-b'
instance_name = 'instance-algo-' + str(uuid.uuid4())
operation = create_instance(compute, project, zone, name=instance_name, instances=[])
```

Which runs without issue. My instance is created based on the correct image, and I am able to discover all the files and directories where they are anticipated.

This is great, but my startup script is not running. When I log in to my instance I do not see the dir `before_all`. If I ssh into the instance I can run `mkdir before_all;`, and it happily runs.

I previously had a much more complex startup script which was not running and simplified to see what I have above.

I am unsure why as the format appears to match what is in [this example from google](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/setting-metadata-and-startup-scripts#test_your_startup_script).

Does anyone see what I may be doing incorrectly here?

Please note, I have tried with and without EOF, with and without semicolon, and with and without `\n`. Scratching my head.

Thank you

Comment: Is it possible that the startup script is executed from a different user that the one you use to connect with `ssh` and therefore it's not in your home directory?

Comment: Here it tells your how to rerun the startup script and where its output is written to. You could include a `pwd` in the startup script and see what you get. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not have "\n" or "EOF". Wherever you got them was just trying to do the equivalent of `"""..."""` in shell scripting.
2. You also should not have any leading space before the `#!`, as this causes it to be ignored. At the moment you have a new line and several spaces before it. Try:

   ```
   """#!/bin/bash
   ...
   """
   ```

   I don't think that is the cause of the issue though, as by default all the commands in your file would be run anyway.
3. Because you specify a relative path to `mkdir` it will create the directory wherever the startup script runs. This is a different location than where you are when you log in (your home directory). If you fix (1) and (2) you will find before_all created somewhere surprising (probably in `/`). If you want `mkdir` to create a directory in your home directory, try using `mkdir /home/YOUR_USERNAME/before_all`. However be aware it will be owned by root instead of your own user.